# ISO image for ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: server, iso, versions

I need an ISO image for ubuntu server 14.04 but apparently all the download links for it have been removed already. I tried looking everywhere for one but I can only find 14.04.1 and 14.04.2. Does anyone know of a link where I can find one?

Answer (score 2):

Check here where there are old releases : 
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/

Answer (score 1):

Mirror homepage image dowload for you

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server